# Is there a way to handle nested Collections more elegantly?

Tags: java, design, data-structures

My question is rather a design question. In my program I got to a data structure that looks something like this:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<A, ConcurrentHashMap<B, ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, C>>> services  = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, ConcurrentHashMap<B, ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, C>>>();
```

Is there a way to handle such a data structure more elegantly? 
Thanks!

**edit**: A, B and C are business classes. An A instance "can have" (as association) many Bs and a B "can have" many mappings Integer-C.

Comment: What types are `A`, `B`, and `C`? It would be easier to answer if I could understand the meaning of three-level nesting of your has maps there.

Comment: Without knowing something about the domain, I don't think there's a general solution. Depending on how the maps are being used, you might consider replace one or more of the maps with classes that export a specific set of properties.

Comment: Consider using objects encapsulating behavior, rather than dumb datastructures. Each of these maps should probably be wrapped into a specific object.

Comment: As an aside, do you really need to use `ConcurrentHashMap`s at every level of nesting?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: I was thinking that it may be so - that there is no "general solution", only a business-related one.

Comment: @JBNizet: That I wanted to avoid, to wrap the maps, because there is really no behaviour that needs to be encapsulated. The classes are quite unrelated from that point of view

Comment: @ovdsrn if you mean "general" as "can be used with any type of object" then yes; but general is usually intended as "can be applied to any situation".

Comment: It isn't necessary for there to be *behaviour* that needs to be encapsulated - just complexity. And there certainly is that here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a class `Triple` with fields for `A`,`B`,`Integer`, override `hashCode()` and `equals()`, and use `Map<Triple,C>` instead of `Map<A,Map<B,Map<Integer,C>>>`

In this approach - you put all elements in one map, with a larger possible range of keys.

Comment: Will the downvoter explain? I assumed here the OP actually is trying to map : `(A,B,Integer)` -> `C`, and thus the nested `Map` usage. The edit also supports my preception.

Comment: Correct, this is what I'm trying to map: (A, B, Integer) to C.

Comment: I'll also add, name the Triple class something meaningful in your business domain.  It must mean _something_ :-)

Comment: Because of the contract of `equals`, this will only work if the keys form an equivalence relation. I recently encountered a situation like this where they didn't: the third component of the key could either be a default value that would accept any instance, or some concrete value, with all concrete values being different from each other. Thus any concrete value would have to be considered equal to the default one, and by transitivity they would all have to be equal to each other, which they weren't.

Answer (score 6):

[I come from C# background, but the answer should apply]

[It doesn't much matter but I assume the last item is **ConcurrentHashMap<C,Integer>**]

You have a function **f** of type **A --> (B --> (C --> int))**
If it is really what you need, I don't have a ready answer. But perhaps, having a function **f** of type **(A x B x C) --> int** would be enough for your purposes.

The difference between two cases is, the first one is lazier, more functional, arguably more elegant and it is possible to have a "partially applied" function around. For example, you have an **a** (of type A) element, you apply **a** to **f** and have a function **g** of type **(B --> (C --> int))** to pass around, send to methods, whatever. However it is a little cumbersome and a little more code to properly initialize the function.

The second is more eager and less elegant, but may be easier to code and understand. All you need to do is to have a generic class **Triple<A,B,C>**, override Equals() and GetHashCode() so that it will have value semantics, (two instances are to be considered equal if they have equal elements) and declare the **ConcurrentHashMap** is from **Triple** to **Integer**. The most obvious cost to pay is you need to have the **A**, **B**, **C** elements ready all at once to create an instance of **Triple** and perform the lookup.

Edit: If the last item is really **ConcurrentHashMap<C,Integer>**, then your generic class will have **A**, **B** and **Integer** fields, and the mapping will be from **Triple<A,B,Integer>** to **C**

Comment: Maybe call it `Triple` instead of `MyClass` to clarify; there are also n-tuple implementations around the web, if you are really lazy.

Comment: Actually, the last map is ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, C>, not ConcurrentHashMap<C, Integer>, but it's just a minor detail, since from your answer I see you understood it correct.